# Internet on network I've been using for years stopped, however it works for other devices

Tags: networking, dns

I've been using this wifi network and one day my laptop simply stopped getting internet from the connection.

1. I still use wifi from this network from my Android phone and from another laptop with Windows
2. with my Ubuntu laptop, I can use wifi from other wifi networks(for example at work)
3. Upon looking in the router settings, I find that my laptop connects to the router
4. I've tried both resetting my laptop and the router, resetting network manager... No result
5. When I `ping 8.8.8.8` there is 100% packet loss
6. Changing the /etc/resolv.conf doesn't do anything... If I restart network manager after changing it, the wifi icon on my bottom bar changes to 2/5 wifi signal but I still cannot access internet
7. I've used Timeshift to revert my root directories to when I still could use internet from this network... Again, no result

EDIT: I can ping other devices on my network.

Comment: can you ping the other machines in your network?  (E.G. The Android / Windows?)

Comment: Yes, I can ping the android phone.

Comment: can you go to a terminal and run the command "route -n"?  what does the line with 0.0.0.0 under Destination have under Gateway?

Comment: Gateway is 192.168.0.6

Comment: "This WiFi network" - is it your network or someone else's? If it is someone else's, they may have blocked your IP address; if so, use Static IP Addressing to change the last octet of your IP address on your Ubuntu laptop. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#ip-addressing

Comment: It's my IP address (well, my brother's) He tried helping me with debugging and fixing my internet so a blocked IP address is definitely not the issue